# Excel formula to compare 2 rows and classify based on the values

Tags: excel-formula

I am new to the Excel formula I am working on the below formula where I have to compare the 2 cells (X13 & AD13) and classify based on the below classifications like the attached image. If AD13 Column is #N/A then it should consider Y13 instead of AD13. Please help me on this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a8N2.jpg)

Comment: I see no formula and the image has no `Y` column. Try [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62289454/edit) your question.

Comment: I do not have the formula I have saved the Y column now

Comment: `=IFERROR(AD13,Y13)` should do right ?